# How to design training loop in RPN?

Tags: faster-r-cnn

I have a short question. I understand the concept of RPN but one small details keeps me from implementing it. How should I design the training loop given that I have to use only a subset of anchor boxes (128 positive and 128 negative). In other words, if the ouput of reg layer is a map of every bounding box, how do I update only the bounding boxes that match my 128 positive/128 negative samples

Comment: Hello. Could you please put your **specific** question in the title? "region proposal network training" is **not** a question and it's very general/vague. Moreover, what do you mean by "reg layer"?

Comment: Ok,i will update the title. Reg layer is regressive layer for bounding box coordinates